# Custom exception Class is not working while using EXCEPTION.class

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-restcontroller

I have a custom exception class as shown below;

```
public class DataSendingError extends Exception {
    
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
     
    public DataSendingError() {
        super();
    }

    public DataSendingError(String errors) {
        super(errors);
        
    }

}
```

PFB the exception handler class:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataSendingError.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> DataSendingErrorCase(DataSendingError ex) {
         System.out.println("inside datasend");
        ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage();
            error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
            error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(error,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
         
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> exceptionHandler2(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("inside common");
        ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        System.out.println("mesage"+ex.getMessage());
        error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

But when I throw a datasending exception, the control is not going inside custom exception but it is going to Exception.class. and e.getmesaage is coming as null.I am throwing the message as shown below:

```
 throw new DataSendingError("Error in processing the request either service is down or invalid input
```

Is I am doing anything wrong here. Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your exception handlers are in a separate class, is it annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`?